# ¿Cómo hacer logout de una aplicación con auth0 con node y express?

Tags: nodejs, express, auth0

Tengo un servidor con node y express y para la autentificación uso auth0.
¿Cómo puedo hacer logout cuando el cliente visite la ruta /salir?
Anexo mi código:

```
app.js
const { auth, requiresAuth } = require('express-openid-connect');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

const config = {
    authRequired: false,
    auth0Logout: true,
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || `http://localhost:${port}`,
    clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    issuerBaseURL: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}`,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    routes: {
        login: false,
    },
};

app.use(auth(config));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.user = req.oidc.user;
    next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'home.html'));
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'login.html'));
});

app.get('/salir', requiresAuth(), (req, res) => {
    try {
        /* Cerrar sesión
        req.logout();
        req.oidc.logout();
        */
        res.redirect('/login');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error durante el cierre de sesión:", error);
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

Intenté cerrar sesión con:

```
       req.logout();
       req.oidc.logout();
```

Pero me marca el siguiente error:

> TypeError: req.logout is not a function ||
> TypeError: req.oidc.logout is not a function